# Multiple Divs with an img tag inside each div separately with Jade Html Pre-Processor

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

The code I have :

```
<div id="cubeSpinner">
    <div class="face one">
        <img src="/images/Windows%20Logo.jpg" class="">
    </div>
    <div class="face two">
        <img src="/images/Turtle.jpg" class="">
    </div>
    <div class="face three">
        <img src="/images/Rainbow%20Worm.jpg" class="">
    </div>
    <div class="face four">
        <img src="/images/Birdman.jpg" class="">
    </div>
</div>
```

How to simplify it using Jade? I know I can use for loop like this for same class for multiple divs but what about the img tags inside them ?Is there a way to simply this in Jade? Thanks in advance

```
- for(var x = 1;x <= 3;x++)
    .nameOfClass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array of objects like below to your jade template

```
var images = [
    {"src": "example1.Jpg", "className":"one"},
    {"src": "exampl2.Jpg", "className":"two"},
    {"src": "exampl3.Jpg", "className":"three"}, 
    {"src": "exampl4.Jpg", "className":"four"}
]
```

In your template  you can display it like this

```
div.cubeSpinner 
    each image in images 
        div.fade(class=image.className)
            img(src=image.src)
```